# Unconfirmed Bitcoin transaction

Tags: blockchain

Please help me.  I have an unconfirmed Bitcoin transaction since three days. Below is the hash ID

a7f5f1989e0bbefeb012b22fbc8f011e5b6b0e66e802ea24242dc1d7878869bb

Answer (score 0):

I would try an ATM if available in your area they seem to be alot faster, I've never waited more than 30 minutes and most of the time they are extremely fast.